# WCF Difference in two URLs that point to the WSDL

Tags: wcf, url, wsdl, soapui

URL in browser: http://localhost:12345/FRB.EC.BMI.WebSvc/Datafaction.svc

shows this:

```
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://sfbztkdev01v.biztalkdev.corp.firstrepublic.com:12345/FRB.EC.BMI.WebSvc/Datafaction.svc?wsdl
```

Why does the URL in the "svcutil" line often differ from what is in the URL, and how do I change it?  I think there is an attribute to add to my code?  Or is there any reason to even be concerned that they are different.

In my specific case, I'm on a VMWare image that has no internet access, and I'm using the port number to avoid conflicts with SharePoint.  When I click on the URL on the svcutil line it loads okay in the browser.  But in SOAP-UI, I'm not getting any response to either that URL or the URL I first mentioned above with "?wsdl" added to the end.

Thanks,

Neal Walters

***Update:*** 
Soap-UI is getting hung on this URL - which it finds inside the above WSDL.

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://FRB.EC.BMI.WebSvc/" location="http://sfbztkdev01v.biztalkdev.corp.firstrepublic.com:12345/FRB.EC.BMI.WebSvc/Datafaction.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" />
```

Even when I save WSDL to file and use that file with SOAP-UI, SOAP-UI is still trying to load the second =wsdl0 from IIS.  It is not getting error nor response.  It just keeps looking for several minutes until I hit cancel.  When I paste same URL with =wsdl0 in URL of browser it opens fine (and then has three more xsd's internal that will have to be opened).

Also please note that I am also trying WCFTestClient.exe and it accepts the URL but when I click the Invoke button gives this:

```
Could not connect to 
http://sfbztkdev01v.biztalkdev.corp.firstrepublic.com:12345/FRB.EC.BMI.WebSvc/Datafaction.svc. TCP error code 10065: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host 192.168.159.129:12345.
```

(I'm not yet sure where the above IP address is coming from.)

Comment: See "how to change wsdl url from internal machine name to public" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007270/wcf-in-azure-how-to-change-wsdl-url-from-internal-machine-name-to-public

Answer (score 1):

`?wsdl` at the end is fine, it is always added. If you can open it in browser just save the wsdl file then open it in SOAP UI

Comment: I'll try that, but any reason Soap-UI cannot get the WSDL from IIS?  Also, I've always wondered why the URL on the svcutil line was difference, so I finally asked - and hope to learn the answer.

Comment: I tried putting file into SOAP-UI, see "update" to original question above.  Thanks!