# How to change WSDL URL from internal machine name to public?

Tags: wcf, azure, wsdl

I have a simple service that I deployed to Azure. It is accessible via:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net/MyTestService.svc
```

The URL to the WSDL uses the internal machine name instead of a public DNS:

```
svcutil.exe http://rd001520d328923a/MyTestService.svc?wsdl
```

Obviously, the WSDL is not accessible from outside the machine with this.

I am aware of a few things that can be changed if you are running this in IIS, or if you do know the url of the service. For example changing the `<serviceMetadata>` config to specify the `httpGetUrl` property, but this will not work as I would have to include the absolute URL. Using a relative URL, it still uses the internal machine name. The real issue is that the WSDL includes URL references with the machine name, therefore rendering it useless.

There are two substandard workarounds:

- It has been suggested that I could grab the WSDL, edit it to fix the URLs and then upload it so it is accessible from a different URL.
- I found a hotfix from early 2010 was available, but there's got to be a better way.

How can this be solved to have the public facing DNS used instead of the machine name?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ok. I have been looking at this for almost a week. I finally found the answer, since it is not easily available I hope this gets indexed and save the time for others.

Basically this overall behavior as a known issue with WCF 3.0/3.5, for which they released a hotfix. You can find out more here: [FIX: URIs in a WCF WSDL document refer to inaccessible internal instances instead of to the load balancer...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842)

I had come across this a few times during my research but never gave it a 2nd thought, mostly because I had no idea how I would deploy a hotfix into Azure.

Fortunately, a Microsoft moderator at the MSDN forums pointed out that this had been fixed in .net 4.0. What this meant was that the "fix" recommended in the KB article above, still applied, with the exception that no hotfix had to be applied. So what is the solution?
Simple, add the following to the config file:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="<name>">
     <!-- Other options would go here -->
     <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
       <defaultPorts> <!-- Use your own port numbers -->
          <add scheme="http" port="81" />
          <add scheme="https" port="444" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
   </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

And that was it.
This would have been a much simpler search if it had been clearer that this issue had now been fixed. Perhaps I didnt look hard enough.

Comment: This work perfectly for us, we were getting localhost references in our wsdl, and now we get the proper external address (.NET 4.0, self-hosted wcf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has saved a bunch of my time.

Comment: Thanks for saving my ... and job !! give url no longer work.

Answer (score 24):

The blog post [Using Request Headers for Metadata Address](http://zamd.net/2010/01/14/using-request-headers-for-metadata-address/) is similar to
[Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42518/victor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017603/52277), but explains that default ports are optional 
and can be omitted:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It also shows how to enable the behavior in the code.

```
sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(new UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior());
```

Comment: I had to mention default port like in @Victor answer .Don't know why ? May be because my wcf application was hosted as child application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the WSDL in order to publish it, or are you just trying to add a reference in another project?

If it's the later, my suggestion is to use the WCF ChannelFactory approach rather than "add service reference". I find it gives me more consistent controllable results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx

I must add, I haven't tried this on Azure.

Comment: Both. We need our partners to consume it.

Comment: Does the WSDL work at the proper URL?  I understand the meta-data page isn't showing it correctly, but for a partner to consume, wouldn't you just hand them the WSDL path directly? vs sending them to a page to get

Comment: The wsdl gets generated with the wrong URLs within as well. So the 'solution' is to manually grab the wsdl, modify it upload into a directory and give them the new path.